How do I add a new entry to my many to many related table in Django?
I have two models Course and Educators. Course has 3 fields course_name, course_educators and course_past_educators which link Educators to Courses by many to many. I want to write a function so that whenever a new entry is added to course_educators that entry will be copied over to course_past_educators.
#models.py
#code for Educators model
class Educators(models.Model):
    educator_name=models.CharField(max_length=20,default=None)
    educator_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='educators_img',default=None)

#code for Courses model
class Course(models.Model):
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    course_educators=models.ManyToManyField(Educators, related_name='current_educators', default=None, blank=True)
    course_past_educators=models.ManyToManyField(Educators, related_name='past_educators', default=None, blank=True)

#views.py
#This is the function I wrote so that entries into course_past_educators are automatically added when course_educators is added with another entry.
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Course.course_educators.through)
def create_past_educator_on_add(sender, instance, action, reverse, model, pk_set, **kwargs):
    if action == 'post_add' and reverse is False:
        currentEducators=instance.course_educators.all()
        for currentEducator in currentEducators:
            instance.course_past_educators.add(currentEducator)

I use Django admin panel to add the educators yet, educators are not being added to course_past_educators. How do I fix this issue?
